# How to type "any object" type?

Tags: typescript

I know I can type a "object" with `object` keyword, but how to type it as "any object" without using the `any` keyword? (because `any` will allow any primitive types like string or number).

```
let a:object;
a.foo // error: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an index type, like `{[key: string]: any}` which says "an object with property names that are strings, whose values are `any`" or `{[key: string]: string | number}` which says the property names will be strings and the values will be strings or numbers.

This does remove a lot of TypeScript's functionality for that object, though, since it can't tell you whether you're using properties that won't exist...